# Context deadline exceeded when runnung helmfile command

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

when I try to deploy a new build of my k8s deployment using this command:

```
helmfile -f <path to helmfile> -e <environment> apply
```

I get this error:

```
FAILED RELEASES:
NAME
xxx-api
in ../../helmfiles/xxx.yaml: failed processing release xxx: command "/bin/helm" exited with non-zero status:

PATH:
  /bin/helm

ARGS:
  0: helm (4 bytes)
  1: upgrade (7 bytes)
  2: --install (9 bytes)
  3: --reset-values (14 bytes)
  4: xxx (12 bytes)
  5: xxx/xxx (25 bytes)
  6: --wait (6 bytes)
  7: --atomic (8 bytes)
  8: --create-namespace (18 bytes)
  9: --namespace (11 bytes)
  10: default (7 bytes)
  11: --values (8 bytes)
  12: /tmp/helmfile829925546/default-xxx-values-8657f7b77f (61 bytes)
  13: --values (8 bytes)
  14: /tmp/helmfile2093074169/default-xxx-values-7948f8657d (62 bytes)
  15: --history-max (13 bytes)
  16: 10 (2 bytes)

ERROR:
  exit status 1

EXIT STATUS
  1

STDERR:
  Error: UPGRADE FAILED: release xxx failed, and has been rolled back due to atomic being set: context deadline exceeded

COMBINED OUTPUT:
  Error: UPGRADE FAILED: release xxx failed, and has been rolled back due to atomic being set: context deadline exceeded
```

Here is the code for that service in the vaules.yaml:

```
xxx:
  _apptype: "xxx"
  _version: v1.1.0
  _enabled: true
  _namespace: default
  replicaCount: 2
  image:
    repository: <repo url>
    container: xxx
    tag: 1.3.1-005
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: artifactory-registry
  probeConfigs:
    livenessProbe:
      enabled: true
    livenessProbeContent:
      httpGet:
        path: /v1/check
    readinessProbe:
      enabled: true
    readinessProbeContent:
      httpGet:
        path: /v1/check
  services:
    service:
      annotations:
        alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: "/v1/check"
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 0.25
      memory: 256Mi
    limits:
      memory: 512Mi
  env:
    com.ids.config.key: BDD6C76E42C76947094218B001B70EB8
    ds.environment: QA
    ds.jurisdiction: US
    ds.url: '"url.com"'
    ds.product: xxx
    environment: qa
    JAVA_OPTS: '"-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2 -Xmx256M"'
  configMap:
    enabled: true
  applicationConfigurations:
    application.properties:
      server.port: 8080
      redis.config.location: classpath:redis-dev.yaml
      pgw.task.queue: xxx-trans-queue
      logging.level.com.paramount: debug
      registration.authorize.url: ds://{authurl}/authorize
      registration.authorize.timeout_ms: 5000
  applicationSecrets:
    enabled: true
  logOverride:
    enabled: true
  springLog: |-
    <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
      <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
              <encoder>
                  <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z, UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
              </encoder>
      </appender>
      <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </root>
      <logger name="url" level="TRACE"/>
    </configuration>
  hpa:
    enabled: false
    maxReplicas: 10
    cpu:
    memory:
    requests:
```

and this is the output of the helmfile diff command:

```
default, xxx-configmap, ConfigMap (v1) has changed:
  # Source: xxx/templates/configmap.yaml
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: xxx
    namespace: "default"
    labels:
      helm.sh/chart: xxx-0.1.2
      app.kubernetes.io/name: xxx-api
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.1.2"
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  data:
    application.properties: |
      info.app.name = xxx
-     management.endpoint.health.show-details = always
      management.endpoints.web.base-path = /xxx
-     management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = info,health
-     management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health = /status
+     management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = info,health,status,ready
      management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.info = /check
      management.health.diskspace.enabled = false
      management.health.mail.enabled = false
      pgw.cloud-watch.name-space = xx
      xxx.task.group = xxx-trans-group
      xxx.task.queue = xxx-trans-queue
      xxx.work-load.check.interval = 30
      xxx.worker.life-check.interval = 2
      xxx.worker.ttl = 5
      redis.config.location = classpath:redis-dev.yaml
      xxx.task.group = xxx-group-process,xxx-group-pull,xxx-group-push
      xxx.task.queue = xxx-QueueProcessRequest,xxx-QueueRuleData,rmg-QueuePushRequest
      server.port = 8080
      server.servlet.context-path = /
+     spring.application.name = Transaction Engine
      spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size = 1
      spring.datasource.url = ds://{dburl?label=monitor}
+     spring.sleuth.sampler.probability = 1
    logback-spring.xml: |-
        <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
          <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
                  <encoder>
                      <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z, UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
                  </encoder>
          </appender>
          <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
          </root>
          <logger name="xxx" level="TRACE"/>
        </configuration>

Upgrading release=xxx, chart=xxx/xxx


default, xxx, Deployment (apps) has changed:
  # Source: xxx/templates/deployment.yaml
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: xxx
    namespace: "default"
    labels:
      helm.sh/chart: xxx-0.1.2
      app.kubernetes.io/name: xxx
      app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.1.2"
      app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    revisionHistoryLimit: 10
    strategy:
      rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 0
      type: RollingUpdate
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: xxx
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: xxx
      spec:
        imagePullSecrets:
          - name: artifactory-registry
        securityContext:
          fsGroup: 2000
          runAsGroup: 3000
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
        containers:
          - name: xxx
            securityContext:
              allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
              readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
-           image: "xxx-docker-snapshot-xxx.jfrog.io/xxx:1.3.1-005"
+           image: "xxx-docker-snapshot-xxx.jfrog.io/xxx:1.4.1"
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: xxx
            ports:
            - name: liveness-port
              containerPort: 8080
            livenessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /xxx/check
                port: liveness-port
              initialDelaySeconds: 120
              periodSeconds: 60
            readinessProbe:
              failureThreshold: 3
              httpGet:
                path: /xxx/status
                port: liveness-port
              periodSeconds: 5
            env:
              - name: TMPDIR
                value: "/tmp"
              - name: logging.config
                value: "/opt/usr/conf/xx/logback-xxx.xml"
              - name: spring.config.location
                value: "/opt/usr/conf/xxx/application.properties"
              - name: JAVA_OPTS
                value: "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2 -Xmx128M"
              - name: com.ids.config.key
                value: BDD6C76E42C76947094218B001B70EB8
              - name: ds.environment
                value: QA
              - name: ds.jurisdiction
                value: US
              - name: ds.product
                value: xxx
              - name: ds.url
                value: "http://example.com"
              - name: environment
                value: qa
              - name: xxx.ClusterName
                value: <clustername>
              - name: xxx.metric.dimension.Namespace
                value: default
              - name: xxx.metric.dimension.PodName
                value: xxx
                memory: 512Mi
              requests:
                cpu: 0.25
                memory: 256Mi
              volumeMounts:
              - name: tmp
                mountPath: /tmp
              - name: application-config
                mountPath: /opt/usr/conf/xxx
                readOnly: true
        volumes:
          - name: tmp
            emptyDir: {}
          - name: application-config
            configMap:
              name: xxx-configmap
              items:
              - key: application.properties
                path: application.properties
              - key: logback-spring.xml
                path: logback-spring.xml
```

please how can I trouble shoot this? I have several other services in the values.yaml and when I tried to update them, it was successful. but this particular service is returning errors.

Comment: This can happen to me if a post-upgrade hook job doesn't complete, among other causes, and if you don't set the `atomic: true` flag then running `helmfile apply` apain will make things move forward.  This is mostly just speculation based on the error message, though; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code input and outputs